# Strange JaxB-Behavior when (un)marshaling XMLGregorianCalender

Tags: java, jaxb

The main class:

```
public class CheckJaxBBehavior
{

    private String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><Date day=\"---10+02:00\" month=\"--09--+02:00\" year=\"2014+02:00\"/>";

    public DateType unmarshal() throws Exception
    {

        ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DateType.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        DateType date = (DateType) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(input);

        return date;

    }

    private static XMLGregorianCalendar createXMLGregorianDate(Date date) throws Exception
    {
        GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        gregorianCalendar.setTime(date);

        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);

        return xmlGregorianCalendar;
    }

    private void marshalAndPrint(DateType dateType) throws Exception
    {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DateType.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(dateType, stringWriter);

        System.out.println(stringWriter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        CheckJaxBBehavior checkIt = new CheckJaxBBehavior();

        DateType dateType = checkIt.unmarshal();

        System.out.println("Day: " + dateType.getDay());
        System.out.println("Month: " + dateType.getMonth());
        System.out.println("Year: " + dateType.getYear());

        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = createXMLGregorianDate(new Date());

        System.out.println(xmlGregorianCalendar.toXMLFormat());

        DateType dateTypeToMarshal = new DateType();
        dateTypeToMarshal.setDay(xmlGregorianCalendar);
        dateTypeToMarshal.setMonth(xmlGregorianCalendar);
        dateTypeToMarshal.setYear(xmlGregorianCalendar);

        checkIt.marshalAndPrint(dateTypeToMarshal);

    }

}
```

The data class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Date")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DateType
{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "day")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "gDay")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar day;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "month")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "gMonth")
//  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=GMonthAdapter.class)
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar month;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "year", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "gYear")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar year;

// getters and setters
}
```

The Output:

```
Day: ---10+02:00
Month: null
Year: 2014+02:00
2014-09-10T17:05:01.768+02:00
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Date day="---10+02:00" month="--09--+02:00" year="2014+02:00"/>
```

My Question:
I'm using jkd 1.7.67 and this is a little bit strange! The input string is exactly the same as the output string, but JaxB isn't able to unmarshal the month. I think the output is not correct, so --09+2:00 must be correct value. Is this an unknown bug or is something wrong with my code? I wrote an adapter to fix this but possibly there is another solution?

Answer (score 0):

The lexical representation for type xs:gMonth is --MM, with an optional time zone following.

If you use

```
"... month=\"--09+02:00\" ... "
```

in the input String xml, month won*t be null any more:

```
Day: ---10+02:00
Month: --09+02:00
Year: 2014+02:00
```

But marshalling exhibits an error in JAXB, since @month has an incorrect value.

Comment: Sorry, had a copy-paste error in the first code snippet. Now according the --M, no hyphens between month and time zone.